# Story in 2000AD comic, read between 1990 and 1996. Before battle, a warrior receives a prophecy that he will die in three days time

Tags: story-identification, comics, prophecy, 2000ad

In one way, he and all his friends are glad of this news. They reason that if he is to die in three days time, he cannot possibly die in today's battle. He can fight incredibly bravely and recklessly and kill a great number of their enemies.
The people in the battle had nothing more advanced than iron age weapons.

It was possibly a Slaine story.

The prophecy came true.

> He was fatally wounded in the first few minutes of the battle, pinned by a huge lance, unable to fight. It took him three days to die.

Comment: Well, that would suck.

Comment: @Moriarty Indeed!